# Divide php loop into two div consecutively

Tags: php, html

I have the following code :

```
<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#e5e5e5;">

<?php 
$c_pk = $rows['id'];
  $sql_i = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `purchasify_items` WHERE cat_id = '$c_pk' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 6");
     if(mysql_num_rows($sql_i)>0) { 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_i)) 
        {

?>

<div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div>

</section>
```

and it show like this

```
<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#e5e5e5;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div></section>

<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#e5e5e5;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div></section>
```

I want a code to have two sections with a difference of background-color like this :

```
<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#e5e5e5;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div></section>

<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#ffffff;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div></section>

<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#e5e5e5;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div></section>

<section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#ffffff;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
.......
</div></div></div></section>
```

Can anyone help ? i'm not good at php

Comment: The PHP code should be above the <section> tag, right?

Comment: yes, it's above the <section> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable to keep track of the row number and color your sections according to that. For example:

```
$c_pk = $rows['id'];
$sql_i = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `purchasify_items` WHERE cat_id = '$c_pk' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 6");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_i)>0) {
        // Initialize the Variable
        $rowNumber = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_i)) 
        {
            // other code

            // Update the current row number
            $rowNumber++;
```

Then using the row number, you can color your sections by checking if they're even or odd like this `if(is_float($rowNumber / 2))` or with the modulo operator: `if($rowNumber%2 == 0)`

Comment: thank you so much for your respond, can you explain to me please how to add those : " if(is_float($rowNumber / 2)) " and " if($rowNumber%2 == 0) "

Comment: Something like: `<section style="background-color:<?= $rowNumber%2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'?>"`

Comment: I tried but i fail , this is what i made , is that right? sorry i'm suck at php

Comment: `<?php 
    $c_pk = $rows['id'];
    $sql_i = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `purchasify_items` `WHERE cat_id = '$c_pk' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 6");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_i)>0) {
        // Initialize the Variable
        $rowNumber = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_i)) 
        {
            // other code

            // Update the current row number
            $rowNumber++;
    ?>
  
    <section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:<?= $rowNumber%2 == 0 ? '#e5e5e5' : '#fff'?>">
    .....
 </div>

    </section>`

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what didn't work

Comment: it only appear the sections with the #fff background color

Comment: It' hard to help you without seeing exactly what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

The logic i have used is if $i is even display first section else    display second section and so on

```
<?php
$i = 2;
while(....){

if($i % 2 == 0){?>


   <section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#e5e5e5;">
   <div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
    .......
  </div></div></div></section>
<?php

}else{?>

    <section class="sppb-section " style="margin:0px;padding:70px 0px;background-color:#ffffff;"><div class="sppb-container"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-sm-12">
    .......
    </div></div></div></section><?php

   }

  $i++;

 }//end while

 ?>
```